# How to collapse ViewController in UISplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I have a `SplitViewController` I have instantiated in code.

```
masterVC = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
masterVC.detailViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailVC];
...
_splitViewController =  [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
_navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterVC];
...
_splitViewController.viewControllers = @[_navigationController, masterVC.detailViewController];
_splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible;
...
self.window.rootViewController = _splitViewController;
```

90% of the time I want both `ViewControllers` to be displayed like in the Settings App, which this does. Now there are however instances where I want my toggle the visibility of my left `_navigationController` for a few minutes and then later go back to the default 2-column setup.

How can I collapse the left side? The only way I can think of would be to redefine the `self.window.rootViewController` and set it to `masterVC.detailViewController`.

Isn't there a more "flexible" way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the display mode button item to hide or show the master.

```
detailViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
detailViewController.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
```

The master-detail project provides sample code to collapse the splitViewController.  Refer to [`UISplitViewControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html) for more details.

**Update:**

Here's the requested delegate code you asked about:

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController ontoPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController {
    if ([secondaryViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] && [[(UINavigationController *)secondaryViewController topViewController] isKindOfClass:[DetailViewController class]] && ([(DetailViewController *)[(UINavigationController *)secondaryViewController topViewController] detailItem] == nil)) {
        // Return YES to indicate that we have handled the collapse by doing nothing; the secondary controller will be discarded.
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (UIViewController *)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController
separateSecondaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController{

    if ([primaryViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        for (UIViewController *controller in [(UINavigationController *)primaryViewController viewControllers]) {
            if ([controller isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] && [[(UINavigationController *)controller visibleViewController] isKindOfClass:[NoteViewController class]]) {
                return controller;
            }
        }
    }

    // No detail view present
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *detailView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailView"];

    // Ensure back button is enabled
    UIViewController *controller = [detailView visibleViewController];
    controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
    controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;

    return detailView;

}
```

Comment: Could you please link to the code sample you are referring to. The ones linked on the `UISplitViewController` documentation don't have this functionality.

Comment: How did the posted code work out for you?  Does the app behave the way you want, now?

Comment: No not really. I did it now by creating `leftBarButtonItems` that call methods which check which `displayMode` is being used and then switch the `displayMode` between `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible` and `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay`

Comment: Did you add the first two lines of code to your detail segue, so the built-in displayMode button would be visible?

Comment: Yes - I also tried reconstructing it with an Example from NSHipster. Maybe this issue is that I am not using Storyboards and Segues. I am coding the views by hand.